# Java KeyBindings Combination does not work

Tags: java, windows, events, combinations, keyevent

I'm struggling with creating a way to identify key combinations. Before I can even set any booleans, I noticed that certain key combinations lead to ignoring other keys.

```
package question;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class Example extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Example() {

    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();

    getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0), "action_a");
    getActionMap().put("action_a", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("A has been pressed!");
        }
    });
    getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "action_s");
    getActionMap().put("action_s", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("S has been pressed!");
        }
    });
    getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0), "action_d");
    getActionMap().put("action_d", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("D has been pressed!"); // This code is reached, even when you are holding down the A key and S key 
        }
    });getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_J, 0), "action_j");
    getActionMap().put("action_j", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("J has been pressed!");
        }
    });
    getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_K, 0), "action_k");
    getActionMap().put("action_k", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("K has been pressed!");
        }
    });
    getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_L, 0), "action_l");
    getActionMap().put("action_l", new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("L has been pressed!"); // This code is never reached when you hold down the J key and K key
        }
    });

    JFrame frame;       
    frame = new JFrame("KeyBinding problem");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();       
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example example = new Example();
}
}
```

I have now used KeyBindings as recommended in order to enable key combinations. But, the problem I'm facing is that **not all keys are registered when certain keys are pressed at once**. With my example, try the following scenario:

Start the example and hold down the A key. The console will continously print out "A has been pressed!". Now, while still holding down the A key, add the S key in addition and hold it down, aswell. The console will now stop printing out "A has been pressed!" and print out "S has been pressed!" continously, instead. Now hold down the A key and the S key and the D key. This will lead to the console continously printing out "D has been pressed!".

Now, restart everything, but instead of using the A, S and D key, use the J, K and L key. **This will only be working with J and K and the L key will be ignored.**

-> I'm using **Windows 8.1 (64-Bit)** by the way. With an Aspire E1-772G laptop.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and how I can work around or even fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

cheers.

***edit**
I have added another example, which also shows the problem visually. It is not possible for me to get all labels to turn red at once. The combination of J+K+L seems problematic for me.  **This cannot be related to the amount of keys pressed at once** , because it's working for 6 keys in my main program, aswell. It's just the combination of J+K, which seems to stop firing the KeyEvents for the L key. This also appears to happen with KeyListeners, as shown in the example below.

```
package question;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.BitSet;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private BitSet bitSet;
private Thread thread;
private JLabel a_key, s_key, d_key, j_key, k_key, l_key;

public Example() {      
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,300));
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();

    bitSet = new BitSet(256);
    thread = new Thread(this);

    a_key = new JLabel("A");
    a_key.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    a_key.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    a_key.setOpaque(true);

    s_key = new JLabel("S");
    s_key.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    s_key.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    s_key.setOpaque(true);

    d_key = new JLabel("D");
    d_key.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    d_key.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    d_key.setOpaque(true);

    j_key = new JLabel("J");
    j_key.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    j_key.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    j_key.setOpaque(true);

    k_key = new JLabel("K");
    k_key.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    k_key.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    k_key.setOpaque(true);

    l_key   = new JLabel("L");
    l_key.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    l_key.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,50));
    l_key.setOpaque(true);

    add(a_key);
    add(s_key);
    add(d_key);
    add(j_key);
    add(k_key);
    add(l_key);

    JFrame frame;       
    frame = new JFrame("Key Event problem");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();       
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    thread.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example example = new Example();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(bitSet.get(keyCode) == false) {
        bitSet.set(keyCode);
    }       
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    bitSet.clear(keyCode);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

private boolean isKeyPressed(int keyCode) {
    return bitSet.get(keyCode);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if(isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
            a_key.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else {
            if(a_key.getBackground() == Color.red) {
                a_key.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }               
        }
        if(isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
            s_key.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else {
            if(s_key.getBackground() == Color.red) {
                s_key.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }               
        }
        if(isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
            d_key.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else {
            if(d_key.getBackground() == Color.red) {
                d_key.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }               
        }
        if(isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_J)) {
            j_key.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else {
            if(j_key.getBackground() == Color.red) {
                j_key.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }               
        }
        if(isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_K)) {
            k_key.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else {
            if(k_key.getBackground() == Color.red) {
                k_key.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }               
        }
        if(isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_L)) {
            l_key.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else {
            if(l_key.getBackground() == Color.red) {
                l_key.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }               
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to get the flood of "pressed" events? I guess I don't really see what the problem is. In general we're only interested in the first event. As for why...we probably have no idea. This type of thing is platform-implemented.

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK 7 on Windows 7. However, in the past I have noticed similar problems when holding down 3 keys at one time (I don't remember the key combination). In that case the keyboard was making a "beeping" sound. I think the problem is the keyboard, although I have no way to verify that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far! @Radiodef : The flood of prints was just the fastest way of showing my problem. My end goal is to have a system that recognizes key combinations. Imagine a piano simulation, in which every key makes a sound. Now, it should be possible to press and hold 3 keys at once in order to create one harmony.

Comment: @camickr I'm using an Aspire E1-772G laptop and I do not get any beeping sound. For the game I'm working on it's even possible to press 6 keys at once and it's working. It's just this J+K combination, which kills other key inputs somehow. So it was working completely fine with your os? I have added a second example, can you test that one, too?

Comment: *"press and hold 3 keys at once"* Well as long as you get the first 'pressed' event for each key (and 'released' event) then everything's peachy. We would normally write some logic to ignore the flooding anyway...

Comment: @Radiodef That's exactly the problem. The first two events are fired, but the third one gets ignored completely. The program enters the keyPressed method for the J key and the K key, but ignores the L key, if they are pressed together. This is not the case for A, S and D and I do not understand why it gets ignored in one case and works for the other. How would one handle the flooding of events? Maybe it's related to the amount of events fired somehow (eventhough I still would not understand why it's working for A,S and D then).

Comment: It's almost certainly the keyboard then. Not much you can do except buy a better keyboard. (Also for future reference you could have probably described the problem better.)

Comment: @iQew, FWIW, as I mentioned I don't have a problem when I use my wireless keyboard. However, when I use my laptop keyboard I have all kinds of problems. JKL works, but ASD doesn't. Neither does ADS or AJD or AKD or ALD, so it is definitely the keyboard. Maybe wireless works better because the old keyboard I had a problem with was connected to the serial port directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly this has something to do with key rollover: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)
Some keyboards give special connections to the WASD keys as they are used frequently in gaming.

Comment: This really sounds like the problem I'm facing. Not much I can do then, I guess :(